# Accessing properties of Child Objects stored in a QML ListModel

Tags: javascript, c++, listview, qml

I want to store objects in a QML ListModel. These objects have several properties. Some are simple strings, others are child objects that also have properties that i wish to access in the QML ListView delegate.

If I do this with javascript objects created in QML, all properties including child object properties are available to the ListView delegate.

```
function addJSObjects(){
    var jsobj1 = {"name": "Aunt Agatha",
               "displayLabel" : {"label" : "Agatha"}};
    listModel.append(jsobj1);
}
```

e.g. in the delegate, *model.displayLabel.label* will return “Agatha”. **—> OK**.

However If I do the same with equivalent C++  custom objects, then I run into problems.
I have an object “Contact” with a property displayLabel that is an instance of the custom object "ContactDisplayLabel". (i.e. the property is a child object).
Both classes are are declared with **Q_GADGET** + **Q_DECLARE_METATYPE** + **qRegisterMetaType**.

The "Contact" object instances are received by QML as a parameter “contact” on a signal from C++

If I append to the QML ListModel like this:

```
onContactFound: {
    console.log("onContactFound signal from C++ for " + contact.displayLabel.label);
    listModel.append({"name": contact.name,
                      "displayLabel": contact.displayLabel});
}
```

then in the ListView delegate, *model.name* is available, but *model.displayLabel* is not defined. However it was defined and available in the signal handler above (as proved by the output of console.log(). **—> NOT OK**.

If I append to the QML ListModel by explicit mapping property by property (effectively a conversion to a javascript object) as below:

```
onContactFound: {
    console.log("onContactFound signal from C++ for " + contact.displayLabel.label);
    listModel.append({"name": contact.name,
                      "displayLabel": {"label": contact.displayLabel.label}});
}
```

then in the ListView delegate *model.displayLabel* is defined, and *model.displayLabel.label* is accessible. **—> OK**.

My real world objects have more properties than in the simplified examples above, but they simple enough to take this pragmatic approach.

But what if my objects were much more complicated, if they had loads of properties and deeply nested child objects?

I suppose I could abandon the QML ListModel, and create a subclass of QAbstractItemModel on the C++ side to store the contacts, but I am reluctant to move more functionality then is required from QML to the C++. Is there a better approach that keeps the QML ListModel?

Comment: Happy new year. :) Interesting question. Probably looking at the source code could help a little bit. Note that in the first case you are probably subject to what is discussed ([here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#get-method)). As for the final choice I would throw in my two cents...it depends. Using a C++ model can solve the problem but you are going to introduce a new full class just for a bunch of string roles. It sounds not worth the effort. I would try to revisit the `Contact` object as a first step.